# Zxing lib refuses to recognize QR code at all

Tags: c#, qr-code, barcode

I have an example QRcode like this:
https://i.imgur.com/Uka0KI6.jpeg

[SecScanQR](https://github.com/Fr4gorSoftware/SecScanQR) app parses it just fine. According to the github sources, it uses [XZing Library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing). However, when I try to parse the same QR code using latest port of [XZing for .NET](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net) - it simply can't find **anything**:

```
Bitmap bitmap = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"d:\Temp\1.bmp") as Bitmap;
var bSource = new BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmap);
BinaryBitmap bbMap2 = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(bSource));
Result result0 = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bbMap2);
if (result0 != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result0.BarcodeFormat.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(result0.Text);
```

The most bizzare things is that [Xzing online scanner](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) itself also can't find any valid barcode. I'm confused, as far as I know, there was no format changes to QRcode spec for the past millennia, so what gives?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that is not a valid QR code, neither my phone nor 2 different online QR code scanning websites recognize it as such. It's also missing the telltale position and alignment markers required on every QR code.

Comment: I did some investigation, and it at least visually looks like an Aztec Code, but not even Aztec Code readers can properly read it. I also setup a local scratch project included ZXing and read it like that, but still doesn't recognize it as anything. Where did you get this image from?

Comment: From boarding pass issued by Pegasus Airlines. As I mentioned earlier, the app in question reads it just fine, as Aztec

Comment: The code you have in your question is not a valid Aztec code either, I tried multiple online readers and they don't work. I did find a Pegasus Airlines boarding pass online ([this one](https://files.sikayetvar.com/complaint/2744/27445445/long-delay-and-absence-of-complimentary-food-on-pegasus-airlines-4.jpg)) and that one scans fine. Your code is also missing the square in the center and has a white layer, which AFAIK is invalid. Compare with the [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Code#/media/File:Azteccodeexample.svg)

Comment: Well, as I have mentioned above the app reads it just fine. Also, it is odd, got it working on https://products.aspose.app/barcode/recognize/aztec

Comment: It's an Aztec code, and scans perfectly fine. Code Corp Engine scans it in less than 50 msec. Comparing the Wiki example and your code, it seems like your code is negative. Maybe this is the reason why. `M10KHVAT/ANASTASIIA  E1MME9P SAWBCNPC 1093..`

Comment: `Code Corp Engine` - sorry, what.